# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function on weebly

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, weebly

I've done every things, but i get `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` on my weebly site!

**My Code:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
$(".popup-wrap").on("click", function() {
    $(".popup-wrap .popup").hide();
    $(".next-popup").show("slow");
});
}, 4000);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="popup-wrap">
<div class="popup">
<b>Get your free</b> 999.9% <b>Gold Bullion</b> Cash Gold!
</div>

<div class="next-popup" style="display: none;">
Almost Done! Complete Free Affiliate Registration to receive Cashgold!
</div>
</div>
```

I'm unable to understand, why this happen, please help :)

Comment: missing  jQuery library in your page, just include it before the code

Comment: @KirkBeard Why you think that? every body is not same....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `jQuery` in your project. That will solve your problem.

Here is how you can do this.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

first include your jquery script

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the $ you need to add the jquery script.Because $ is not defined in normal javascript it's a library method of jquery.
You can download the script from this [link](https://jquery.com/download/). Then add in your project Example :

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`
.Or you can use cdn from [here](https://code.jquery.com/)